# how to submit react component in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to update isShownSideMenu state when submit HumburgerMenu component

But don't get HumburgerMenu component dom using a getByTestId,etc.

How can I press HumburgerMenu?

Target component:

```
const Header = () => {
  const [isShownSideMenu, setIsShownSideMenu] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const onClickHumburgerMenu = () => {
    setIsShownSideMenu(!isShownSideMenu)
  }

  return (
    <IsShownSideMenuContext.Provider value={isShownSideMenu}>
      <HeaderRoot>
        <Flex alignItems='center' height='100%'>
          <Box>
            <Link href='/' passHref>
              <a data-testId={isShownSideMenu}>
                <AppLogo />
              </a>
            </Link>
          </Box>
          <Box height='100%'>
            <HumburgerMenu onClick={onClickHumburgerMenu} />
          </Box>
        </Flex>
        <SideMenu />  
      </HeaderRoot>
    </IsShownSideMenuContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Test file:

```
describe('Header', () => {
    test('should toggle', () => {
        render(<Header />)
        const menu = screen.queryByTestId('menu');
        userEvent.click(menu);
        expect(screen.queryByTestId(true)).toBeTruthy(); // failre
    })
})
```

Comment: And does it _have_ that test ID? We can't see that component, give a [mre].

Comment: Set `data-testId="menu"` instead of a boolean.